# $(document).ready called inside an external function?

Tags: jquery

I saw some jquery code on the Net somewhere, that took this form :

```
<script>            
function doSomething(message)
{   
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        alert(message);
        });
};
</script>
```

i.e. an external function ("doSomething") which has $(document).ready inside it. I'm confused because isn't the code under $(document).ready triggered when the DOM is loaded ? Its like having an event handler inside a function (?). Does this form of code make sense to anyone ? Thanks.

Comment: This kind of patterns are used in event handler methods when there are multiple event handleres are there for same event and internally they trigger another events or do ajax calls and modify the DOM. This is to ensure DOM is ready to manuplate again before calling another functions in your event handler code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was probably an error on the part of the original coder. You *could* do that, but you'd want to call `doSomething` pretty early on. Note that if the DOM is already ready when you call `ready`, jQuery will call the code, so it will happen either way, but it won't happen until someone, somewhere, calls `doSomething`. I can't see much purpose to the pattern, so unless you have some strong argument for using it — and given the question, I suspect you don't :-) — you can safely ignore it.

Comment: I know this is old but I have a scenario.  Lets say you want to call a XML/JSON file right when the page is fired, and on complete of that function update some DOM elements with the received response.  If that response is quicker than the page loading and the DOM elements haven't loaded yet, they don't get updated.  Could doSomething() be the success callback and work in this fashion?  So if it does complete early, everything will still work?

Comment: @iLLin: That's a perfectly reasonable use-case, I'd think. So you trigger the ajax request with a script very high up in the document (in the `head`, I'd think), using `ready` in the success callback. Perfectly reasonable. I'm not sure the ajax request will happen a *lot* sooner than it would if you put the script at the bottom of the `body` tag (and then you wouldn't have to bother with `ready`), but no harm in letting the browser know early what you want it to do.

Answer (score 8):

It makes sense. $(document).ready registers an event handler that is fired when the DOM is fully loaded. The anonymous function that is passed to it, is that handler. If you register that handler after the DOM is loaded, it is fired immediately.

Javascript can be executed before the DOM is fully loaded, so what this function does, it actually registers messages that are not to be shown before the DOM is loaded. You can use this construct if you don't want the message to be displayed before the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not exactly sure of the reason. Maybe, the original coder found a browser that stops rendering the page when a message is shown. If that would happen, the user is looking at some icky half-rendered page until the messages is closed. Have tried if this might actually happen.

Answer (score 3):

> Does this form of code make sense to anyone ?

No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

$(document).ready(); essentially registers the function to be executed when the DOM is ready. However in this case, the programmer had nested this in the function. This means that it will not be added to the .ready() until he make an invocation to the function doSomething();

You can try it out with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomething(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            alert('here');

        });
    }
    doSomething();
</script>
```

Place this at various parts of your HTML and check it out (:

Cheers!