# jquery slidetoggle is not hiding

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a login hyperlink. so when i click on it a login form with id=nd_login_form will show.

```
<li class="active"><a href="#nd_login_form" ><?php _e('Login', 'ninety'); ?></a></li>
```

this is the login link. the form is:

```
    <form action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?wcz" method="post" class="nd_form" id="nd_login_form" style="z-index:100;background:gainsboro;position:absolute;"><div class="nd_form_inner"> 

    <p><label for="nd_username"><?php _e('Username','ninety'); ?>:</label> <input type="text" class="text" name="log" id="nd_username" placeholder="<?php _e('Username', 'ninety'); ?>" /></p> 
    <p><label for="nd_password"><?php _e('Password','ninety'); ?>:</label> <input type="password" class="text" name="pwd" id="nd_password" placeholder="<?php _e('Password','ninety'); ?>" /></p> 

<input type="submit" class="button" value="<?php _e('Login &rarr;','ninety'); ?>" /> 
        <input name="nd_login" type="hidden" value="true"  /> 
                <input name="redirect_to" type="hidden" id="redirect_to" value="<?php echo nd_login_current_url(); ?>"  /> 
    </p> 
</div></form>
```

the jquery script i used is:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
         (function ($) { 
      $(document).ready(function() { 
             $("#nd_login_form").slideUp(); 
      $(".active").click(function () { 
         $("#nd_login_form").slideToggle("fast"); 
      }); 
  }); 
    })(jQuery); 
         </script>
```

So the problem is when the document is ready first the form will not appear correctly and it will show up on clicking the login link. till now everything is fine. but on the next click on the login hyperlink the form is not hiding or sliding up. can anyone help me to find the mistake in here.??

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ld8SN/1/

Comment: first remove the self exe function, you dont need that when you document ready... so is trying to call the function before the document is ready,... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027337/document-ready-called-inside-an-external-function

Comment: it works fine ...  http://jsfiddle.net/Ld8SN/3/

Comment: i have same issue...in fiddle its working but on deploying it in the site it is not...on the second click it is not hiding..plzz help ..

Comment: then it has to be something else causing the error, share the link or add more code, since this is **not** the part with the problem

Comment: if you want to hide the form initially you can use `.hide()` instead of `.slideup()` in document ready. Then just write a `.slideToggle()` in `.click()`. like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/Q7aah/

Comment: @CJRamki: i tired by changing slideup to hide. no change occurs.

Comment: @CJRamki well if you put it like that, is faster to do it in css, since it will load with the DOM http://jsfiddle.net/Q7aah/3/

Comment: @barbieegal do you have any error in the console?

Comment: yeah... @jycr753 I agree with you... This post owner not interacting with us...

Comment: @jycr753: there is no error is showing in the console that is the main  failure. thts y i can't figure out what i the actual problem. my code is exactly like in the post with some changes in the id names.but i updated similar to this. i will give link to my site. in the home page top along with twitter icons there is the login link. http://rotarymetropolis.com/

Comment: is just a css problem, too many position absolutes, i will look at it well later on,... but is not jquery or javascript problem, is just a bad placement of css or html

Comment: @jycr753:: okay.. waiting for your rply..u r the only hope i hve sir..  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the script with this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#nd_login_form").slideDown(); 
    $(".active").on('click',function () { 
        $("#nd_login_form").slideToggle("fast"); 
    }); 
});
```

you have two docuent.ready functions in your script. and at first you want to show the form use the slideDown() class.[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbandi/Ld8SN/5/)

Comment: please adjust the form code correctly. I have just changed the JQuery code

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display:none` to the form style

```
 <form action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?wcz" method="post" 
    class="nd_form" 
    id="nd_login_form" 
    style="z-index:100;background:gainsboro;position:absolute;display:none">
```

and jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $(".active").on('click',function () { 
        $("#nd_login_form").slideToggle("fast"); 
    }); 
});
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UDpdk/)